# image.DecodeConfig Doesn't Wait For EOF

Tags: image, go, concurrency, pipe

When reading into multiple writers at the same time (`io.MultiWriter`), I found `image.DecodeConfig` is causing the reading function (`io.Copy` in my case) to block.

I recreated the problem as simply as I could, using the example code for `image.DecodeConfig` from the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/image#example-package-DecodeConfig).

Here is the [playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/xwC6EglUAB3).

If you run the code as-is, it will block. If you uncomment the `io.Discard`ing, the reading continues and `io.Copy` can complete.

```
func main() {
    reader := base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, strings.NewReader(data))

    pr, pw := io.Pipe()

    ch := make(chan error)

    go func() {
        config, format, err := image.DecodeConfig(pr)
        if err != nil {
            ch <- err
            return
        }
        // *** Uncomment below to remove deadlock ***
        /*
            if _, err := io.Copy(io.Discard, pr); err != nil {
                ch <- err
                return
            }
        */
        fmt.Println("Width:", config.Width, "Height:", config.Height, "Format:", format)
        ch <- nil
    }()

    go func() {
        defer pw.Close()

        if _, err := io.Copy(pw, reader); err != nil {
            ch <- err
            return
        }

        fmt.Println("finished copying")
        ch <- nil
    }()

    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        if err := <-ch; err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("done...")
}
```

I can't imagine discarding the rest of the unread bytes is the proper way to deal with this situation. What is a better solution?